# Use tstamp property in tasks in a project

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant, cruisecontrol

Can I use tstamp property BuildDate in a nant task to an xecutable task in cruise control net as given below? if that is possible, Is my usage correct?

```
<tstamp property="BuildDate" pattern="dd-mmm-yy" verbose="true" />
```

---

```
  <exec executable="C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe">
    <buildArgs>/C rename "D:\Disk Images\Disk1" ICE_$(BuildDate)"</buildArgs>
    <buildTimeoutSeconds>10</buildTimeoutSeconds>
  </exec>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a first look everything looks fine so far... except for this: Use curly braces when accessing the property. So it's `Disk1" ICE_${BuildDate}"` instead of `Disk1" ICE_$(BuildDate)"`.

**UPDATE**: Wait a minute... You're trying to pass the property back from NAnt to CCNET? No, that won't work. You may use the `BuildDate` property inside NAnt only.

Comment: Is there any way to get date in dd-mmm-yy in cruise control net?

Comment: Question: you're trying to rename a file, right? This can be done easily inside NAnt. Why don't you do this?

Answer (score 0):

A cumbersome way to achieve this would be to write your values into a xml file using nant, and then use the `modificationReader` task.